# How to pass Artifactory credentials to bitbake

Tags: docker, artifactory, yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to run `bitbake` inside a Docker container:

```
docker exec -i yocto /bin/bash -c "bitbake ${IMAGE} --runall=fetch"
```

I got error:

```
ERROR: <RESOURCE-vXXX> do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export PATH="..."; export HOME="..."; /usr/bin/env wget -t 2 -T 30 --passive-ftp --no-check-certificate -O /path/to/archive.tar.gz.tmp -P /path/to/downloads 'https://<ARTIFACTORY.COM>/path/to/archive.tar.gz' --progress=dot -v failed with exit code 6, no output
ERROR: <RESOURCE-vXXX> do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'https://<ARTIFACTORY.COM>/path/to/archive.tar.gz;unpack=1;name=vendor;subdir=/path/to/<RESOURCE>')
```

[Exit code 6](https://gist.github.com/cosimo/5747881) means *"Username/password authentication failure"*. So I guess I need somehow to pass Artifatory credentials/API-key either to `bitbake` directly or to `docker exec`

Are there any existing approaches to do that?

**Update**

I also tried to add

```
SRC_URI += \"https://<ARTIFACTORY.COM>;protocol=https;user=${ARTIFACTORY_USER}:${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWD}\"
```

to conf/local.conf, but now I get

```
Bitbake Fetcher Error: NoChecksumError('Missing SRC_URI checksum', 'https://<ARTIFACTORY.COM>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by creating `.netrc` file with credentials in Home directory:

```
docker exec -i yocto /bin/bash -c """echo 'machine https://<ARTIFACTORY.COM>' > ~/.netrc &&
                                     echo 'login ${ARTIFACTORY_USER}' >> ~/.netrc &&
                                     echo 'password ${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWD}' >> ~/.netrc
                                  """
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing credentials, you can mount the host's `.ssh` dir inside docker as `volume` while running docker e.g

`docker run -it -v $HOME/.ssh:/home/<user>/.ssh <your_remaining-parameters>`

Also to speed up the yocto build process you can mount `_git-repositories-cache` as well

Comment: I've added option to mount shared .ssh folder but that only allowed to connect to Artifactory, but still need to authorize... Also I added `SSTATE_DIR` to local.conf for caching. Did you mean something else by `_git-repositories-cache`?